# Set environment variables then run script in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins, Groovy and pipelines. I have created a simple pipeline stage like so:

```
//working build but not setting env variables
node('build-01') {
    stage('Building') {
        echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.BUILD_ID}) on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
        try {
            sh 'ls -l'
            //ls shows the damn file
            sh '. setup-target'
        } catch(all) { 
            sh "echo 'Failed to run setup-target script with error: ' ${all}"
        }
    }    
}
```

This works. But I want to modify/add environment variables to the session running this script (this script is a bash file with the correct shebang line on top). So I did:

```
node('build-01') {
    withEnv(["CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}", "SDK_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}"]){
        stage('Building') {
            echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.BUILD_ID}) on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            try {
                sh 'ls -l'
                //ls shows the damn file
                sh '. setup-target'
            } catch(all) { 
                sh "echo 'Failed to run setup-target script with error: ' ${all}"
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

This errors out with:

> > /home/jenkins-sw/ci/workspace/myWorkSpace@tmp/durable-6d30b48d/script.sh: line 1: .: setup-target: file not found

and

> > Failed to run setup-target script with error:  hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1

But the environment variables are set, I check this by doing a `sh 'printenv'` right below the `ls -l` line. Interestingly `ls -l` does show the script.

What am I missing?

### UPDATE

The following:

```
node('build-01') {
    withEnv(["CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}", "SDK_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}"]){
        stage('Building') {
            echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.BUILD_ID}) on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            try {
                sh 'ls -l'
                //ls shows the damn file
                sh './setup-target'
            } catch(all) { 
                sh "echo 'Failed to run setup-target script with error: ' ${all}"
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

results in:

> > /home/jenkins-sw/ci/workspace/myWorkSpace@tmp/durable-6d30b48d/script.sh: line 1: ./setup-target: Permission denied

Interesting. How is withEnv effecting permissions? What?! And if I chmod that file to have permissions, i get a new error, something related to "missing workspace".

Comment: check the output of `sh 'ls -l'` in second case,  to see current login user has execution right on file `setup-target`

Comment: In the first case I was able to execute the script. Why would withEnv change that fact? Nevertheless, I will check. Thank you.

Comment: `ls -l` is identical in both the cases shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was cloning directly into the workspace and then setting my environment variables to point to the workspace as well. I modified both those things. I now create a dir in my workspace and clone into it and I also set my environment variables to directories inside my workspace. Like so:

```
node('build-01') {
    withEnv(["CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}/cmake_install", "SDK_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}/sdk"]){
        stage('Building') {
            echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.BUILD_ID}) on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            try {
                sh 'ls -l'
                //ls shows the damn file
                dir('path/to/checkout/') {
                    sh '. ./setup-target'
                }
            } catch(all) { 
                sh "echo 'Failed to run setup-target script with error: ' ${all}"
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that either `CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR` or  `SDK_INSTALL_DIR` are on the path.

Instead of `sh '. setup-target'` you should `sh './setup-target'`.

Comment: without the `.` at the beginning I am no longer sourcing the script into my current session, right? I need to source into current session. I tried `. ./setup-targe` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I had to learn about the `.` in shell scripts (that it is an equivalent of source). In general I think my answer still holds, `source` executes the script for you, where `./setup-target` requires execution rights. One of your variables is most likely on your path. So still no magic.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR is on the path? Do you mean the path that CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR contains is appended to $PATH? If so, I just did a `echo $PATH` and no, the paths that CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR and SDK_INSTALL_DIR hold are not in $PATH. Also source (or `.`) does not just execute the script, it ensures the script runs as part the current shell process.